# Не работает click по классу добавленному через classList

Tags: javascript, click

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Я добавляю класс к элементу по клику.

```
on('click', '.mobile-nav-toggle', function(e) {
select('.nav-link').classList.toggle('nav-link-mobile')
})
```

После чего я хочу через клик по этому классу выполнить еще код, но ничего не работает.

```
on('click', '.nav-link-mobile', function(e) {
тут код
})
```

Comment: Не понятно что за функция `on()` у тебя используется... Так желательно делать полные тестовые примеры. Иначе не понятно что там у тебя делается...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что обработчик событий, назначенный на элемент с классом `.nav-link-mobile`, не срабатывает, потому что этот элемент не существует на момент назначения обработчика.

Можно использовать делегирование событий. То есть, вместо того, чтобы назначать обработчик событий на элемент с классом `.nav-link-mobile`, можно назначить обработчик на родительский элемент, который уже существует на момент назначения обработчика.

Например, если родительский элемент имеет класс `.nav-links-container`, то можно использовать следующий код:

```js
// Назначить обработчик на родительский элемент .nav-links-container
on('click', '.nav-links-container', function(e) {
  // Проверить, что кликнули на элемент с классом .nav-link-mobile
  if (e.target.matches('.nav-link-mobile')) {
    // Тут код для обработки клика на элементе .nav-link-mobile
  }
});
```